# App Force closing and val Null Pointer Exception in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I am running my app in phone. On that app suddenly force closed and I checked in LogCat.
On that, I see Null Pointer Exception In Variable. I don't know what I can do?

I also Add "?" Null but it did not solve the problem? Is any alternative code available?

This is my code MainActivity

```
package com.lordshiva.smartapp

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val cube: CardView = findViewById(R.id.cardCube)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        cube?.setOnClickListener{
            Toast.makeText(this,"cube clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

This my Activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    >

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/headText"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/_3d_objects"
       android:textSize="30sp"
       android:layout_margin="12dp"
       android:textStyle="bold"
       android:textColor="@color/black"
      />

   <ScrollView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
       >

   <GridLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:columnCount="3"
       android:layout_margin="20dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
       >

      <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
          android:id="@+id/cardCube"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="fill"
          android:layout_columnWeight="1"
          android:layout_rowWeight="1"
          android:layout_row="0"
          android:layout_column="0"
          app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
          app:cardElevation="8dp"
          app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
         <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:orientation="vertical"
             tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">

             <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@mipmap/cube_shiv"
                android:contentDescription="@string/todo"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="@string/cube"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

         </LinearLayout>

      </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

      <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
          android:id="@+id/cardBee"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="fill"
          android:layout_columnWeight="1"
          android:layout_rowWeight="1"
          android:layout_row="0"
          android:layout_column="1"
          app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
          app:cardElevation="8dp"
          app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
         <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:orientation="vertical"
             tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@mipmap/bee_shiv_foreground"
                android:contentDescription="@string/todo"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="@string/bee"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

         </LinearLayout>

      </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

      <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
          android:id="@+id/cardAdd"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="fill"
          android:layout_columnWeight="1"
          android:layout_rowWeight="1"
          android:layout_row="1"
          android:layout_column="0"
          app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
          app:cardElevation="8dp"
          app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
         <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24"
                android:contentDescription="@string/todo"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="@string/add"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

         </LinearLayout>

      </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

   </GridLayout>
   </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I guess setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) needs to be called before the val cube: CardView = findViewById(R.id.cardCube).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you are getting your cardCude before setting layout that is why you are getting null so get your views after setting layout check below:

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val cube: CardView = findViewById(R.id.cardCube)

        cube?.setOnClickListener{
            Toast.makeText(this,"cube clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```